# How can I implement SAML 2.0 with ASP.NET without the use of federation services?

Tags: asp.net, saml

We manage a website that runs of the .NET 4 framework and we need to implement SAML 2.0 to support single sign on. We do not wish to run Active Directory federation services as all user accounts are stored in a SQL server. What do I need to consider when developing a single sign on service whereby we are the identity provider?

Comment: Are you open to other federation technologies that would allow the continued use of your SQL database? I can't quite tell from your statement.

Comment: @Ian - Yes however considering data is held across non-SQL databases as well, am looking for a solution that would accommodate both SQL database and non-SQL databases.

Answer (score 1):

I work with SiteMinder Federation Services (SMFSS) and Federtation Manager for CA.  Are you planning on also doing Authorization for the SP based on Attributes? Do you have an Authorization SSO Solution already?  IF so what is it?  If it is SiteMinde then the fastes easiest to impliment solution would be SMFSS.  Aside from from ServletExec and Java JDK bugs which are pretty much fixed up now I can get customers who have never used Federation up and running in a day for a SAML 2.0 POC. So, if you do have SiteMinder I would give that a try and I am sure you will be quite pleased. If not we also have Federtion Manager which can run as a proxy into your site or not. We have customers who do things such as use the SiteMinder access logs to charge users for access to SP sites a certain charge per access. We have the attribute Authority so that if you want to provide Authorization based on user attributes you can do that. If SMFSS is on the SO side you can just have the attributes stored on the SPO sides session store. Can you tell more about your use case?  When SiteMinder was orignally created one of the uses cases was for SSO between different web servers, etc.

Let me know if I can help with any follow up questions and have a splendid day!

Thanks!
Crissy Krueger Stone
CA SiteMinder Support

Comment: Sorry Crissy for not get back to you sooner. Are you able to drop me an email with more details at peanutsmonkey@gmail.com?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your initial requirements,  you should take a look at PingFederate from Ping Identity [Note: I do work for Ping I'd]. It can support multiple databases and directories simultaneously as well as provide multi-protocol support in both an IDP and SP role. We can also support different development languages you may have beyond. NET.

HTH- Ian

Comment: Sorry Ian for not get back to you sooner. Are you able to drop me an email with more details at peanutsmonkey@gmail.com?